# jQuery live scroll

Tags: jquery

Подскажите, как можно скроллить элементы сгенерированные с помощью ajax например? Т.е. что применить там, где нужно вместо

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
      console.log($(document).height());
});
```

сделать так:

```
$(window).live('scroll', function() {
      console.log($(document).height());
});
```

В интернетах пишут, что scroll не поддерживает live, но не пишут что с этим делать. Копать в сторону delegate?

Comment: Не много не понял что именно нужно сделать, отловить скролл сгенерированных элементов или именно проскролить их?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#elem').bind('scroll', function(){
    alert('bar');
});
```

delegate, к сожалению, не поможет (хотя вдруг какой-то умелец найдется?)

Answer (score 3):

Можно пойти на хитрость. В общем, смысл в том, что перед тем, как начать скроллить какой-то элемент страницы, должно быть событие, которое этому предшествует. При этом событии, мы "вешаем прослушку". Я выбрал **mouseenter**, вы - какое посчитаете нужным. В общем, [вот что получилось](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/qCEF7/).